# Convert multiple TDMS metadata files in one Excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, file

I have multiple TDMS files in a source folder. I use below code to read the metadata out of those files, that works perfectly now. However, to improve my code I would like to merge all those files in 1 excel file and everytime I receive new TDMS files and run my code, the metadata will be added at the bottom of my Excel sheet.

This is the code I have right now:

```
from nptdms import TdmsFile as td
import os
import pandas as pd


source = 'c:\data\AM\Desktop\location'

for file in os.listdir(source):
    if file.endswith('.tdms'):
        tdms_path = os.path.join(source + '\\' + file)
#        print(tdms_path)
        
        metadata = td.read_metadata(tdms_path)
#        print(metadata)
        
        b = metadata.properties
        
        print(b)
        
        for f in b:
            df = pd.DataFrame([metadata.properties.values()], columns=metadata.properties.keys())
            df.to_excel('c:\data\AM\Desktop\destination\\*.xlsx')
```

Comment: how do you know what file is new and what is not? what if you miss a day of running the script?

Comment: @Datanovice I will make the script run automatically using the Task Scheduler of windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first concatenate the results of files metadata then write to excel outside the for loop:

```
from nptdms import TdmsFile as td
import os
import pandas as pd

source = 'c:\data\AM\Desktop\location'
dfs = []

for file in os.listdir(source):
    if file.endswith('.tdms'):
        tdms_path = os.path.join(source + '\\' + file)
        metadata = td.read_metadata(tdms_path)
        dfs.append(pd.DataFrame([metadata.properties.values()], columns=metadata.properties.keys()))

df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.to_excel('c:\data\AM\Desktop\destination\\*.xlsx')
```

Comment: Aha, thank you. I got it. did not fill in the name of the excel file. Thank you very much men!

Comment: Could you help me with an other question? The question is named ''Loading multiple text files into MySQL workbench using python''. You can see it once you click on my profile.

Answer (score 0):

This is not using Python. But a simple batch script "type" can append all the file to txt oor csv file.
Try this in command prompt pr save the code as filename.bat:

```
type "c:\data\AM\Desktop\location*.tdms" > "Combined.csv"
```

You can also call this command line using os module.

```
import os
os.popen("type c:\data\AM\Desktop\location*.tdms > Combined.csv")
```

Comment: I need to do it in Python

Comment: Thank you but Mohamed's answer suited me better.